# I'm trying to cut a string with a number of bytes. What is the problem with this for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

Sorry in advance for the beginner question, but I'm quite stuck and keen to learn.

I am trying to echo a string (in hex) and then cut a piece of that with cut command. It looks like this:

```
for y in "${Offset}"; do
  echo "${entry}" | cut -b 60-$y
done
```

Where echo ${Offset} results in

```
75 67 69 129 67 567 69
```

I would like each entry to be printed, and then cut from the 60th byte until the respective number in $Offset.

So the first entry would be cut 60-75.

However, I get an error:

```
cut: 67: No such file or directory
cut: 69: No such file or directory
cut: 129: No such file or directory
cut: 67: No such file or directory
cut: 567: No such file or directory
cut: 69: No such file or directory
```

I tried adding/removing parentheses around each variable but never got the right result. 
Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE: updated the code with changed from markp-fuso. However, this codes still does not work as intended. I would like to print every entry based on the respective offset, but it goes wrong. This prints every entry seven times, where each time is based on seven different offsets. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash

MESSAGES=$( sqlite3 -csv file.db 'SELECT quote(data) FROM messages' | tr -d "X'" )

for entry in ${MESSAGES}; do

  Offset='75 67 69 129 67 567 69'
  for y in $Offset; do
    echo "${entry:59:(y-59)}"
  done
done
```

```
echo ${MESSAGES}
```

Results in seven strings with minimal length 80 bytes and max 600.
My output should be:

String one: cut by first offset

String two: cut by second offset
and so on...

Comment: Remove `"${entry}" | cut -b 60-` and see what doesn't happen.

Comment: Taking into account the answer from Cameron Little, I removed the parentheses around `${Offset}`. When I only echo $y like you suggest, exactly that happens.

Comment: @Tim  Cameron said to remove the **quotes** ... so instead of `echo "${entry}"` you should use `echo ${entry}`; not sure what you're referring to by '... tried adding/removing parentheses around each variable...' ... ???

Comment: based on your latest update it sounds like you're getting exactly what you've coded ... for each new `${entry}` you're looping through the 7 different offsets which means you're getting 7 sets of outputs for each `${entry}`; if that's not what you want ... then update your question with some sample data for `${MESSAGES}` and the desired output

Comment: No, that is not what I'm looking for. I want to use each individual offset for the individual result from $MESSAGES.

Comment: to loop \*bytes\* in unicode stings, set `LC_ALL=C`, for example as `local LC_ALL=C` in the function body

Answer (score 0):

In order for `for` to iterate over each space-separated "word" in `$Offset`, you need to get rid of the quotes, which are making it read as a single variable.

```sh
for y in ${Offset}; do
  echo "${entry}" | cut -b 60-$y
done
```

Comment: Correct answer.  Tim, it is easy to debug scripts with the `-x` option.  Notice that the OP did not report "cut: 75 No such file or directory".  That implies your command expands to:
`echo "${entry}" | cut -b 60-75 67 69 129 67 567 69`

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the suggestion! Exactly this: `echo "${entry}" | cut -b 60-75 67 69 129 67 567 69` happens. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: You remove the quotes around $Offset, as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the sub-process that's going to be invoked due to the `| cut ...`, we could look at a comparable parameter expansion solution ...

Quick reminder on how to extract a substring from a variable:

```
${variable:start_position:length}
```

Keeping in mind that the first character in `${variable}` is in position zero/0.

Next, we need to convert each individual offset (`y`) into a 'length':

```
length=$((y-60+1))
```

Rolling these changes into your code (and removing the quotes from around `${Offset}`) gives us:

```
for y in ${Offset}
do
    start=$((60-1))
    length=$((y-60+1))
    echo "${entry:${start}:${length}}"

    #echo "${entry:59:(y-59)}"
done
```

NOTE: You can also replace the `start/length/echo` with the single commented-out `echo`.

Using a smaller data set for demo purposes, and using 3 (instead of 60) as the start of our extraction:

```
# base-10 character position
#                 1         2
#        123456789012345678901234567
$ entry='123456789ABCDEFGHIabcdefghi'

$ echo ${#entry}      # length of entry?
27

$ Offset='5 8 10 13 20'

$ for y in ${Offset}
do
    start=$((3-1))
    length=$((y-3+1))
    echo "${entry:${start}:${length}}"
done

345                  # 3-5
345678               # 3-8
3456789A             # 3-10
3456789ABCD          # 3-13
3456789ABCDEFGHIab   # 3-20
```

And consolidating the `start/length/echo` into a single `echo`:

```
$ for y in ${Offset}
do
    echo "${entry:2:(y-2)}"
done

345                  # 3-5
345678               # 3-8
3456789A             # 3-10
3456789ABCD          # 3-13
3456789ABCDEFGHIab   # 3-20
```

Comment: Thank you for the efficient solution. However, it uses the same entry every time. The loop in the question is actually nested in another for loop: `for entry in ${MESSAGES}; do `. Do you know why it doesn't use the next entry for the next y?

Comment: The (original) question says nothing about an outer loop for setting `${entry}`; having said that, the proposed answer should still work as the inner workings of a larger/outer loop; as for why your code isn't working ... *shrug* ... I have no idea what your code looks like; you would need to a) update your question with your full/complete issue or b) open a new question to address the (separate) issue of an outer loop that's setting the `${entry}` variable